# Tweepy Error - Python -

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, geany, python-twitter

I install Tweepy and Python-Twitter and try basic code

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=["X"],
                  consumer_secret=["X"],
                  access_token_key=["35X-X"],
                  access_token_secret=["X"])
print(api.VerifyCredentials())
```

and i tried to run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweepy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import twitter
  File "/home/rodney/twitter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "/home/rodney/tweepy.py", line 2, in <module>
    api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=["X"],
AttributeError: module 'twitter' has no attribute 'Api'
```

get this error what i do:

if try code:

```
import twitter
import tweepy
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=["X"],
                  consumer_secret=["X"],
                  access_token_key=["35X-X"],
                  access_token_secret=["X"])
print(api.VerifyCredentials())
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweepy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "/home/rodney/tweepy.py", line 2, in <module>
    import twitter
  File "/home/rodney/twitter.py", line 10, in <module>
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
For what you want to do here is the code using tweepy
    `import tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(key, secret)
    resp= tweepy.API(auth)`

The rest is upon you whatever you want to do. For that you will need cursors, which can be found over here `http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/cursor_tutorial.html`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweepy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "/home/rodney/tweepy.py", line 2, in <module>
    api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=["X"],
NameError: name 'twitter' is not defined

Comment: see the second line i am not calling twitter i am calling `tweepy.api`.

Comment: Here is the code to authenticate and get the tweets using tweepy

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweepy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "/home/rodney/tweepy.py", line 2, in <module>
    import twitter
  File "/home/rodney/twitter.py", line 10, in <module>
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'

Answer (score 1):

Tweepy takes two steps to set up authorisation, as detailed in the [documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/auth_tutorial.html):

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = 'XX'
consumer_secret = 'XXX'
access_token = 'XXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

print api.verify_credentials()
```

Tweepy is also distinct from python-twitter - you probably don't need both. I'd also avoid calling your file `tweepy.py` as this could cause confusion in imports later on.

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install python-twitter
```

Working fine on python3 and python2

Comment: i tried and error: Cannot uninstall requirement twitter, not installed

Comment: then just install python-twitter

Answer (score -1):

If working on pycharm IDE try to add the tweepy library from File-->setting
Link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKzfNBTRx5U